# I know this is basic, but I'm brand new to Python. I'm using Python 3 and my coding problem I cannot get the print function to work with the input

Tags: python

```
#Area of a rectangle base*height/2
base = input("Base of the rectangle: ")
height = input("Height of the rectangle: ")
area = (base*height)/2

print(area)
```

When I run the code and I enter the 3 and 5 I get this error:

```
Base of the rectangle: 3                                                                             
Height of the rectangle: 5                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                   
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                
    area = (base*height)/2                                                                           
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. You cannot multiply strings.

Comment: base and height are **strings**.

Comment: Wrap both `input` functions in `int()`.

Comment: input() returns a string which means base and height are both strings. If you cast these to integers by surrounding input() by int() you should see it works :)

Comment: Isn’t the area of a square/rectangle base * height?  Div 2 gives the area of a triangle.